# Up-/downsampling with One vs. rest classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I have a data set (tf-idf weighted words) with multiple classes that I try to predict. My classes are imbalanced. I would like to use the One vs. rest classification approach with some classifiers (eg. Multinomial Naive Bayes) using the OneVsRestClassifier from sklearn.

Additionally, I would like to use the imbalanced-learn package (most likely one of the combinations of up- and downsampling) to enhance my data. The normal approach of using imbalanced-learn is:

```
from imblearn.combine import SMOTEENN
smote_enn = SMOTEENN(random_state=0)
X_resampled, y_resampled = smote_enn.fit_resample(X, y)
```

I now have a data set with roughly the same number of cases for every label. I then would use the classifier on the resampled data.

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
ovr = OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB())
ovr.fit(X_resampled, y_resampled)
```

But: now there is a huge imbalance for every label when it's fitted, because I have in total more than 50 labels. Right? I imagine that I need to apply the up-/downsampling method for every label instead of doing it once at the beginning. How can I use the resampling for every label?

Comment: Not able to understand. Why is there label imbalance:-  `"now there is a huge imbalance for every label when it's fitted"` after you have resampled the data?

Comment: Because as far as I understand, for n labels the one vs. rest classifiers fits n models. Every model predicts one label and takes all the other labels as negative examples. Therefore, if I have 50 labels, each say with 1000 examples, for every model that is fitted there would be 1000 positive examples and 49000 negative examples. That's the huge imbalance.

Comment: So do you want the up/down-sampling to happen after the data in divided into n-models?

Comment: I want the resamplung happen for every model that is fitted, so that the number of positive and negative examples is roughly equal for all of the n models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the discussion in comments, what you want can be done like this:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from imblearn.combine import SMOTEENN

# Observe how I imported Pipeline from IMBLEARN and not SKLEARN
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

# This pipeline will resample the data and  
# pass the output to MultinomialNB
pipe = Pipeline([('sampl', SMOTEENN()), 
                 ('clf', MultinomialNB())])

# OVR will transform the `y` as you know and 
# then pass single label data to different copies of pipe 
# multiple times (as many labels in data)
ovr = OneVsRestClassifier(pipe)
ovr.fit(X, y)
```

**Explanation of code**:

- Step 1: `OneVsRestClassifier` will create multiple columns of `y`. One for each label, where that label is positive and all other are negative.
- Step 2: For each label, `OneVsRestClassifier` will clone the supplied `pipe` estimator and pass the individual data to it.
- Step 3:

  a. Each copy of `pipe` will get a different version of `y`, which is passed to `SMOTEENN` inside it and so will do a different sampling to balance the classes there.

  b. The second part of `pipe` (`clf`) will get that balanced dataset for each label as you wanted.
- Step 4: During prediction time, the sampling part will be turned off, so the data will reach the `clf` as it is. The sklearn pipeline doesnt handle that part so thats why I used `imblearn.pipeline`.

Hope this helps.